# Kivy reload() image not updating in app window

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am currently making a Python app using Kivy and KivyMD for UI. The general idea of my app is for the user to press a button and a QR code image will appear in the app window. If the user presses the button again, a new QR code image should appear. I am trying to use the Kivy `reload()` function to update the QR code image but it only updates the image in the directory and not in the app window.

***Kivy Builder load string:***

```
 Window.size = (320, 500)

 main_kv = """

 BoxLayout:
     orientation: 'vertical'
      size_hint_y: None
      height: self.minimum_height
      spacing: dp(10)
 MDLabel:
      font_name: 'Roboto-Italic'
      theme_text_color: 'Primary'
      text: "Public Key:"
      halign: 'center'
      pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .90}
      font_size: 20
 Image:
      id:qr
      source: 'qr.jpg'
      size: self.texture_size
 MDLabel:
      font_name: 'Roboto-Italic'
      theme_text_color: 'Primary'
      text: "Private Key:"
      halign: 'center'
      pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .50}
      font_size: 20

 MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
      text: "Generate Keys"
      icon: 'polymer'
      opposite_colors: True
      pos_hint: {'center_x': .5 , 'center_y': .08}
      elevation: 10
      on_press: app.b32Keys()
      opposite_colors: True


"""
```

***Python Code:***

```
class KnixBTC(App):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    theme_cls.primary_palette = 'DeepPurple'
    theme_cls.accent_palette = 'Orange'
    theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'

    def build(self):
        self.main_widget = Builder.load_string(main_kv)
        return self.main_widget

    def b32Keys(self):
        image = Image(source='qr.jpg', nocache=True)
        privateKey = PrivateKey.random()
        private = privateKey.wif(compressed=True)
        publicKey = privateKey.to_public()
        bech32 = publicKey.to_address('P2WPKH')
        genQR = qrcode.make(bech32)
        genQR.save("qr.jpg")
        image.reload()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    KnixBTC().run()
```

Comment: When do you call b32Keys?

Comment: Try adding `nocache=True` to your `Image()` call.

Comment: I guess I did not put my code for my button in my original post but I call b32Keys() in the button code. I put the nocache=True after the "source = 'qr.pg' " and It still does not in the app window. I just update my original code with my button to call b32Keys()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`image` is different from `qr`, the first one is created each time the b32Keys function is invoked and the second is the one shown, so reloading `image` does not reload `qr`. So the solution is to access `qr` directly, in this case you must use the root and id:

```
def b32Keys(self):
    privateKey = PrivateKey.random()
    private = privateKey.wif(compressed=True)
    publicKey = privateKey.to_public()
    bech32 = publicKey.to_address('P2WPKH')
    genQR = qrcode.make(bech32)
    genQR.save("qr.jpg")
    self.main_widget.ids.qr.reload()
```

Comment: Awesome! That works just the way I want it too!!! Thank you so much for the help!!!